# Google Guava Cache, refreshing the expire timeout

Tags: java, caching, collections, guava

I have the following, which sets a default expire timeout for all new entries.

```
Cache<String, Tracker> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
expireAfterAccess( expire , TimeUnit.MINUTES ).build();
```

How can I refresh the expire access, after it has been populated?

Of course, one solution might be to remove the item and reinsert it, but that might be more **expensive** than what is already possible in other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just access the element you want to refresh using `cache.getIfPresent(key)`. According to [Guava wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Timed_Eviction) (emphasis mine):

> [`expireAfterAccess(long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterAccess(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) Only expire entries after the specified duration has passed **since the entry was last accessed by a read or a write**. Note that the order in which entries are evicted will be similar to that of size-based eviction.

so it should do exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sweet! I use cache.get() though, i hope it behaves the same :)

Comment: Yes, according to `expireAfterAccess` documentation: _"Access time is reset by all cache read and write operations (including Cache.asMap().get(Object) and Cache.asMap().put(K, V)), but not by operations on the collection-views of Cache.asMap()."_, so `get(K ,Callable)` is OK, too.